# Mergining excel sheet in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, merging-data, exploratory-data-analysis

Having an two excel sheet as follows:

[image: img1][image: sheet2]

Need to merge these two excel sheet using pandas.Second sheet needs to be merge with the first excel.
The output will be want in the following format.

[image: new]

Comment: Can you provide some data as dict and code that you tried?

Comment: temp=sheet1.merge(sheet2, how='left') I tried this code. Didn't come output as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have df1 and df2
and you wanna merge the two dataframes together on the same start
here is sample:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='Start')
```